# Cakephp how to set array values so i can insert two records at same time on my DB?

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

After fill a form with two adresses: Billing address and personal address(using FormHelper):

```
...
<div><?php echo $this->Form->input('Contact.1.name'); ?></div></td>
<td> <div>name1</div>
<div><?php echo $this->Form->input('Contact.2.name'); ?></div></td>
...
```

, i get this array:

```
'Contact' => array(
    (int) 1 => array(
        'name' => 'asdf',
        'nif' => '123123123',
        'address' => 'pcsa',
        'zipcode' => '1234',
        'street' => 'das'
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'name' => 'fsad',
        'nif' => '321321321',
        'address' => 'asdp',
        'zipcode' => '1234',
        'street' => 'fas'
    )
)
```

But before i save this array to send data for DB i need to set manually user_id=32 (for example).

Can you give me any suggestion how to do that? so i can get this result:

```
'Contact' => array(
    (int) 1 => array(
        'name' => 'asdf',
        'nif' => '123123123',
        'address' => 'pcsa',
        'zipcode' => '1234',
        'street' => 'das',
            'user_id' => 32      <----------------
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'name' => 'fsad',
        'nif' => '321321321',
        'address' => 'asdp',
        'zipcode' => '1234',
        'street' => 'fas',
            'user_id' => 39       <--------------- 
    )
)
```

My purpose here is to save data from a form to a table "contacts" for the same user_id. for that reason i can't use user_id as a input form, i need to do that after form and before inserte on my DB. For that reason, how can i set this array with user_id?

Comment: What's wrong with the "i need do something like this" solution?

Comment: $this->request->data['Contact'][1]['user_id'] = 32; doesn't work!

Comment: Shame on me..Sorry @AD7six you are right! it works. I was mistaken.. thanks for your observation.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the [CakePHP Hash library](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html) you can do stuff like

```
$this->request->data = Hash::insert($this->request->data, 'Contact.{n}.user_id', 123);
```

Example

```
$contacts = array(
    'Contact' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'asdf',
            'nif' => '123123123',
            'address' => 'pcsa',
            'zipcode' => '1234',
            'street' => 'das'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'fsad',
            'nif' => '321321321',
            'address' => 'asdp',
            'zipcode' => '1234',
            'street' => 'fas'
        )
    )
);

$contacts = HASH::insert($contacts, 'Contact.{n}.user_id', 123);
pr($contacts);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [Contact] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => asdf
                    [nif] => 123123123
                    [address] => pcsa
                    [zipcode] => 1234
                    [street] => das
                    [user_id] => 123
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => fsad
                    [nif] => 321321321
                    [address] => asdp
                    [zipcode] => 1234
                    [street] => fas
                    [user_id] => 123
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I tried to do this, `$this->request->data['Contact'] = Hash::insert($this->request->data['Contact'], '{n}.Contact', array('user_id' => '32'));`, but it doesn't do it right it insert something like this:
 `'Contact' => array(
  (int) 1 => array(
   'name' => 'sadd',
   'nif' => '134421',
   'address' => 'dda',
   'zipcode' => '1234',
   'street' => 'adas',
   'Contact' => array(
    'user_id' => '32'
   )
  )`

Comment: Thanks,@Devin, but how can i give distinct values? On the first one [type] => billing and in the second [type] => personal.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
foreach ($this->request->data['Contact'] as &$contact) {
    $contact['user_id'] = 32;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer which seems to work fine, but how can i give two distinct values for each sub array,for example: one $contact[type] = 'billing' and the second one $contact[type] = 'personal' .

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for your suggestions, but this is the final solution for me.

```
$this->request->data['Contact'][1]['user_id'] = 32;
$this->request->data['Contact'][2]['user_id'] = 39;
```

Simply as that, i didn't see it because i was debugging wrong.